# I want to prevent myself disabling services on my own personal computer (Windows 11)

Tags: administrator, windows-services

I hope this is the right forum for this question. I have a service that regulates my access to the internet and applications such as games, if I stop it the service has some sort of way of restarting itself. However, I've just found out recently whilst poking with an interest in getting process development myself, is that I can just go into the Service manager and disable it and it won't it won't be able to restart. As someone with ADHD, this discovery is absolutely disastrous .

A lot of the literature I've found out on how I would restrict my access services is aimed at intermediate to advanced sys admins who manage organizations, there seems to be steps missed out that a beginner would need.

What I understand is that I would need to make and Admin account on my machine, then use that to remove certain privilages from my personal account, does that sound like the right direction? If so, how would I go about removing my ability to disabling services afterwards?

Thank you all in advance

Comment: A standard User Account cannot disable services.  Set up a Standard User account (not Admin) and give it a user name and password.  Use that and not your administrator account for most purposes.

Comment: Since you already have administrative access, and you're worried about the temptation to bypass User account restrictions, **after you create a non-admin User account, have a reliable friend change the Admin password.** Have her or him put a copy of the password in a safe place, which you would have difficulty accessing, but could get to if need be (e.g., installing software).

Comment: These sound like a good suggestions, I will try and let you know how it works out. I've developed a method of password management for these specific types of password I do not want to be easily accessible to myself, requires a bit calculation to work them out, this adds enough frustration to the process to want to carry out that behavior.

Comment: This suggestion worked, I'll mark it as the answer if someone wants to answer the question with it.